# visual basic thread handling (wait for other thread)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, printing

I have the following sub which starts another another sub in a new thread when a new file is created. The second sub is printing the file (PDF). So far all works fine.

```
Private Sub PrintPDF(Datei As String)
    Try
        Dim startPrint As New Thread(AddressOf PrintNow)
        startPrint.IsBackground = False
        startPrint.Start(Datei)
    Catch ex As Exception
        sendmail(__FUNCTION__(), ex.Message, True)
        Err.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now my problem. In some cases I have to print the file two or more times (different paper trays). When two files for the the same printer a created the same time it the following output happens:

Print 1 - Page 1
Print 2 - Page 1
Print 1 - Page 2
Print 2 - Page 2

Which printer is used I know from the filename:
00_99999999~FreePDF~1~0~1~1_K1_K2_AA_AA~0~16~201703020716530219.pdf
-> FreePDF

Here now my question: Is there a possibility to wait for the end of the thread if the same printer is used by another thread? If there is no running thread for the printer a parallel printing is ok and wanted.

Thank you in advance.

Michael

Comment: You could either try checking the thread IsAlive property, or the ThreadState property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Look into a [**`ManualResetEvent`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [**Thread Barrier**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: There's also [**`Thread.Join()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx), which is probably better in your case than the other methods I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synchronize the critical section of code used to print. Use a dictionary of printer name to object to organize the locking objects.

```
Private dictionaryLock As New Object()
Private printerLocks As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

Private Sub PrintNow(datei As String)
    Dim printerName = datei.Split("~"c)(1)
    SyncLock dictionaryLock
        If Not printerLocks.ContainsKey(printerName) Then
            printerLocks.Add(printerName, New Object())
        End If
    End SyncLock
    SyncLock printerLocks(printerName)
        Console.WriteLine("Started printing on {0} - {1}", printerName, datei)
        Thread.Sleep(2000) ' print here
        Console.WriteLine("Finished printing on {0} - {1}", printerName, datei)
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

Tested with this

```
Sub Main()
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF1~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF2~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF7~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF1~2")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF4~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF2~2")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF1~3")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF3~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF3~2")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF5~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF1~4")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF2~3")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF6~1")
    PrintPDF("0~FreePDF3~3")
End Sub
```

> Started printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF4 - 0~FreePDF4~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF7 - 0~FreePDF7~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF5 - 0~FreePDF5~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF6 - 0~FreePDF6~1
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF4 - 0~FreePDF4~1
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~2
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~2
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF7 - 0~FreePDF7~1
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF5 - 0~FreePDF5~1
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~1
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~2
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF6 - 0~FreePDF6~1
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~2
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~3
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~2
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~3
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~2
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~3
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~3
>   
> Started printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~4
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF2 - 0~FreePDF2~3
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF3 - 0~FreePDF3~3
>   
> Finished printing on FreePDF1 - 0~FreePDF1~4

Comment: Thank for your answer. In a first test it looks very good!!! On Friday we will print about 50 documents at once. I will post a comment if this practice test also works fine.